# Parse File name in Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a filename in a format like:

```
 Master.csv-yyyy-mm-dd.txt
example:- Master.csv.2016-07-06.txt
```

I want substring from that in the following format.

```
  YY-MM
```

please help me quickly

Comment: echo ${fileName:10:12}
but it's output is 16-07-06 .   i want only 16-07.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
date_temp=$(echo Master.csv.2016-07-06.txt | awk -F. '{print $3}')
date -d"$date_temp" +%y-%m
16-07
```

Comment: can i assign it to any variable name? like folderName=date

Comment: yes , you should be able to do

Comment: yes it's working . thanks

Comment: how can we get from this string hello_2016-07-06.txt

Comment: you did get me . i want to extract YY-MM from this string hello_2016-07-06.txt

Answer (score 1):

try this;

```
 ls M*.txt | awk -F. '{print substr($3,3,5)}'

user@user:/tmp$ ls M*.txt
Master.csv.2016-07-05.txt  Master.csv.2016-07-06.txt

user@user:/tmp$ ls M*.txt | awk -F. '{print substr($3,3,5)}'
16-07
16-07
```

if folder includes filename as hello_2016-07-06.txt, you can try this;

```
ls *.txt | grep -oP '[\d]+-[\d]+-[\d]+' | awk -F- '{print substr($1,3,2)"-"$2}'
```

Comment: how to assign into variable ? and print that variable

Answer (score 0):

One liner with Python:

```
echo 'Master.csv.2016-07-06.txt' | xargs -I{} python -c "import re; print re.search('\d{2}\-\d{2}', '{}').group(0)"
```